# When printing auth::user() in the other page, it becomes null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still new in here and new in Laravel. Last time, when I redirected to another page and printed `Auth::user()` in the **blade.php**, it worked fine. Now, when I am printing `Auth::user()->name` on the redirected page, it becomes null.

Here's my code:

**route.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/login');
});
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});
Route::get('/register',function(){
    return view('register');
});
Route::get('/home',function(){
    return view('home');
});
Route::post('/loginController','userController@login');
Route::post('/registerController','userController@register');
```

**userController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests;

class userController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $req){
        $name = $req->name;
        $email = $req->email;
        $password = $req->password;
        $confirm = $req->confirm;
        $validator = Validator::make($req->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:5',
            'confirm' => 'same:password',
        ]);
        if($validator->fails()){

        }
        else{
            echo 'Masuk!';
        }
    }
    public function login(Request $req){
        $email = $req->email;
        $password = $req->password;
        $attempt = Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password]);
        if($attempt){
            //dd(Auth::user()->name);
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home | Siloam Hospital</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="Assets/style/bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/style/bootstrap/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="Assets/style/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/style/home.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- navigation -->
<header>
    <nav>

        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a href="home.html">Home</a>
                <div class="nav-item-block active"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a href="appointment.html">Appointment</a>
                <div class="nav-item-block"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a href="diagnose.html">Diagnose</a>
                <div class="nav-item-block"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a href="schedule.html">Doctor Schedule</a>
                <div class="nav-item-block"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav nav-right">
            <div class="profile-drop-down">
                <a id="profile-drop-down-btn" href="#">Username<span class="caret"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="profile-drop-down-content">
                <div class="show-profile">
                    <a href="profile.html">Show Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="log-out">
                    <a href="login.html">Log Out</a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- <button type="button" id="wlButton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('profile-drop-down-btn');
    var content = document.getElementById('profile-drop-down-content');
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-drop-down')[0];
    var containerLink = container.childNodes[1];
    var opened = false;
    btn.onclick = function(){
        if(opened){
            content.style.display = 'block';
            container.style.backgroundColor = "#1d2675";
            containerLink.style.color = "#fff";
        } 
        else{
            content.style.display = 'none';
            container.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
            containerLink.style.color = "#1d2675";
        }
        opened = !opened;
    }
</script>


<!-- login form content -->
<section id="section-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 profile-container">
            <div class="col-xs-3 profile-image-container">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="images/Willy Pranata.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 profile-content">
                <div class="title">
                    <p><strong>Name : <span class="profile-name">{{Auth::user()->name}}</span></strong></p>
                </div>
                My Insurance :
                <div class="profile-assurance-container">
                    <ul>
                        <li>BPJS</li>
                        <li>Prudential</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</section>

<section id="section-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 appointment-container">
            <div class="title">
                Upcoming Appointment
            </div>
            <div class="appointment-content">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Lastname</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>
                        <td>john@example.com</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Mary</td>
                        <td>Moe</td>
                        <td>mary@example.com</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>July</td>
                        <td>Dooley</td>
                        <td>july@example.com</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer class="text-center">
    <div class="footer-text">
        <a href="https://siloamhospitals.com/about-us.html">About Us</a>
        <a href="https://siloamhospitals.com/investor-relations.html">Investor Relations</a>
        <a href="https://siloamhospitals.com/news-events/media-coverage.html?EN">News & Events</a>
        <a href="https://siloamhospitals.com/contact-us.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a style="border-right: none;" href="https://siloamhospitals.com/faq.html">FAQ</a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copy">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2016. Siloam Hospitals Groups</p>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: When I used `dd` in the login function controller, it went just fine, but when I printed on **home.blade.php**, it displayed an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

I also did some research but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: try auth()->user(); instead Auth::user();

Comment: i did but the result is same

Comment: right, then make sure middleware 'web' is attached to the web routes, wrapp your routes with `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // your routes
});`

Comment: the result is same...

Comment: you mean like this right? Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
 Route::get('/home',function(){
  return view('home');
 });
});

Comment: yes. still same? If yes  then in your blade do a `@php dd(Auth::user()) @endphp`

Comment: the result is null

Comment: Let's login first by visiting /login (: Maybe your session expired!!

Comment: my test flow: /login -> /loginController -> /home.... when i came at /home, my Auth becomes null....

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to access the Auth facade you need to pass through the authentication middleware. How you pass through that is up to you. 
The quickest way to do that in your case is to change the line of the route

```
Route::get('/home',function(){
    return view('home');
});
```

to:

```
Route::get('/home',function(){
    return view('home');
})->middleware('auth');
```

if you don't assign the middleware the Auth facade will not be accessible which means the object returned will be null. Hence the error of trying to access a property of a non object.

Comment: Test: when i try to execute the route /home after login, the middleware didn't   accepts the Auth::attempt, hence it return to /login

Comment: is the login you tried to used already registered? It should be in your database.

Comment: i seeded the data beforehand